# Middleware Not Handling Next-Auth Sign Out Properly

Tags: next.js, middleware, next-auth

I have a navigation bar that is a header on all pages of my application. On my navigation bar there is a sign out button. The user can click sign out when they are on a page that requires the user to be authenticated (middleware is used to determine what pages need authentication). When this happens I want to renavigate the user back to a page where they do not have to be authenticated to be on. I have tried doing that with my following code via router pushing and then using the signOut function from next-auth. When I do this on my web server, however, the web page flashes to the home screen but immediately prompts the user to sign back in. I would like the user to be navigated back to the home screen where they can manually sign back in. If anyone can explain why this happens and how I can fix it to perform the way I want that would be greatly appreciated!

Code With Sign Out Function

```js
"use client"

import { useSession,signOut } from 'next-auth/react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'

export default function SignOut() {

    const router = useRouter();
    
    const { data: session } = useSession();

    const handleSignOut = async () => {
        router.push('/');
        await signOut();
      };

    return (
        <li className="list-none">
            <p style={{ marginRight: '1rem' }}>Welcome, {session?.user?.name} </p>
            <button onClick={handleSignOut} className="text-sm">
                Sign Out
            </button>
        </li>
        
    )
}
```

Middleware Code

```js
export { default } from 'next-auth/middleware'

export const config = { matcher: [
    '/dashboard'
]}
```